# Mysql: How to set up properly a procedure call inside init_connect variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, init

I want to store the activity of each session user at very high level into a table.
I wrote a procedure "audit.login_trigger". I have created the schema needed(audit DB and Table). It is some thing like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE audit.login_trigger()
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO audit.audit_connect (thread_id, user, login_ts)
  VALUES (CONNECTION_ID(), USER(), NOW());
END;
```

I have place this inside "init_connect".

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect="CALL audit.login_trigger()";
```

I want this to be executed for every user connection. I gave EXECUTE privileges on this PROCEDURE to root user but when the root user logged in, it is not populating the audit schema as expected. What might went wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since this user is named "root" I wonder if it has super privileges. If it does, then note that init_connect doesn't fire for super users.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for calling stored procs from init_connect. Some people may have success with it or just propose that it works without thorough testing. Here is a link to an aws discussion [link here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=111750). Maybe it varies by build version.

Comment: I got this to work fine in 5.7.13.  However, it would not work in 5.6.24 or 5.6.31. When I say *this to work* I mean anything to work. For `root` one would not want it to work anyway due to technical reasons too long to comment about.